# edit file 1 with contents of file 2 using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file `file1` containing some information for a number of people which is spread over multiple lines and fields and there will also be multiple entries for each person.
In addition I have another file `file2` containing a list of peoples names.

I would like to use the names in `file2` to **remove all the corresponding entries in `file1`**. (Or conversely `file2` could be a list of the names to be kept?)

So for example if `file2` contained the name `Harry` and `file1` looked like:

```
name  
Tom  
info  
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
1234  
name
Dick  
info   
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
8765  
name 
Harry  
info 
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
5678  
name
Tom  
info
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
9876
```

Then my output would be:

```
name  
Tom  
info  
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
1234  
name
Dick  
info   
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
8765  
name 
Tom  
info
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
field1  field2  field3…..  
9876
```

does anyone have any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: Does a record always begin with `name` on a single line?

Comment: Did you try something?? Why specifically AWK?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
awk -f rem.awk input.txt
```

where `input.txt` is your input file and `rem.awk` is

```
BEGIN {
    while ((getline line < "names.txt") > 0) {
        sub(/[ \t]*$/,"",line) #In case there are trailing spaces..
        name[line]++;
    }
}

((NR-1) % 7)==0 {i=0}
((NR-1) % 7)==1 {rname=$1}
{rec[i++]=$0}

((NR-1) % 7)==6 { 
    if (! (rname in name)) {
        for (j=0; j<=6; j++) {
            print rec[j]
        }
    }
    next
}
```

and `names.txt` are the file with the names.. (Note: the program assumes that each name in `names.txt` is on a new line)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt using `sed` followed by `pcregrep`

First create a file with list of desired search patterns from `file2` using `sed`. Let's say output file is called `search_names`

```
sed -r 's/(\w+)/name.*?\\n\1.*?(\\n|.)*?\\d{4}/' file2 | tee search_names
```

Then you can feed in created pattern file with `-f` option to `pcregrep`. Use `-M` option for multiline search.

**Remove entries** - use `-v` to invert match

```
pcregrep -vM -f search_names file1
```

**Retain entries**

```
pcregrep -M -f search_names file1
```

Tested above commands with your sample input and it worked fine on my system.

Answer (score -1):

This method did not take the assumption that each entry for every person has only 7 lines.

```
n=`cat names.dat | wc -l` ; awk -v len="$n" ' BEGIN {bPrint = 1; }  { if (NR <= len) { a[$1]=$1 ; } else {     if ($0 == "name") { if (bPrint) print ; bPrint = 1 ;  }     else { if (a[$1] != "" ) { bPrint = 0 ; }   if (bPrint) print ; } } }  ' names.dat a.dat
```